why useEffectLayout can avoid flicker? with the fact that screen is re-rendered after
I understand that useEffectLayout runs before screen re-rendering and the purpose of useEffectLayout is for avoiding flicker.
So, I expect after the state update in useEffectLayout , it wont re-render the screen immediately but update the value in state first. However, I saw that the useEffect is executed after useEffectLayout.
That means screen was re-rendered after useEffectLayout with the old state value.
So I dont understand why useEffectLayout can avoid flicker.
import { useEffect, useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  console.log("count in code: ", count);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("count in useeffect: ", count);
  }, [count]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("count in uselayout: ", count);
    setCount(1);
  }, [count]);

  return <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>;
}


Re: "I saw that the useEffect is executed after useEffectLayout. ¶ That means screen was re-rendered after useEffectLayout with the old state value": Sorry if I'm being obtuse, but — why does it mean that? Your effect doesn't have any side-effects, so why would it cause a re-render?

it lies in the sequence of events during rendering in React (see it below)
Render phases

React calculates how your component should look and prepares the updates
React applies those updates to the DOM, making the changes ready for display
useLayoutEffect hook runs right after the DOM is updated but before the screen shows anything. it lets you make adjustments here that will be applied before the screen updates
the browser then paints the updated content to the screen
useEffect hook runs after the screen updates, so any changes here will cause another re-render but only after the user has already seen the initial update

utilizing the useLayoutEffect allows you to make changes to the DOM or state just after the DOM updates but before the browser has rendered the changes to the screen.
You can read more about useLayoutEffect in the official React documentation here.
